# When does the NDA on iOS 11 expire?

Tags: ios

Not really a programming question but it is related, can't seem to find any info. I read [APPLE BETA SOFTWARE PROGRAM AGREEMENT](https://beta.apple.com/sp/ja/betaprogram/legal?locale=ja). I know I can’t disclose, publish, or otherwise disseminate any Confidential Information to anyone other than individuals who are enrolled in the same individual seed as you, or as otherwise expressly permitted or agreed to in writing by Apple. But I can not I'm not sure if iOS 11 **GM** is BETA SOFTWARE. When does the NDA on iOS 11 expire if GM is BETA SOFTWARE? My assumption is it expires when it's released on the 19th?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a legal issue, not a programming issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the release date. In theory, there is a possibility that a GM can undergo a change if they find a major issue. So they like to keep the "Beta" clause, although in practice the use of a GM as the final version is encouraged.